# k* reproduction values?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, k-means, nearest-neighbor, quantization

I am reading about Product Quantization, from section II.A page 3 of [PQ for NNS](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00514462/PDF/jegou_pq_postprint.pdf), that says:

> ..all subquantizers have the same finite number k* of reproduction values. In that case the number of centroids is (k*)^m

where `m` is the number of subvectors.

However, I do not get k* at all! I mean in vector quantization we assign every vector to k centroids. In produce quantization, we assign every subvector to k centroids. How did k* come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `k*` is the number of centroids in each subspace, and `k` is the number of centroids in the whole space.

For example if the data is 2d, like `(x, y)`, and we treat each dimension as a subspace, and do kmeans with say `k*=3` respectively, we'll get 3 centroids in each subspace, `{x1, x2, x3}` and `{y1, y2, y3}`.

Then there'll be `3^2=9` possible centroids in the whole space, which are<sup>*</sup> `(x1, y1)`, `(x1, y2)`, `(x1, y3)`, `(x2, y1)`...

In this way we can get a large number of centroids (`2^64` in the paper) using a small amount of memory, because we don't have to store all `k*^m` centorids, we only need to store `k*` centroids in each subspace.

Edit:
In above the example, the number of subspaces `m=2`, number of centroids in each subspace `k*=3`, number of centroids the whole subspace `k=3^2`, number of dimensions of each subspace `D*=1`, number of floating points to store `mD*k*=Dk*=6`.

---

*<sub>the cartesian product of x and y</sub>

Comment: Thus we have to store `m * k*` centroids in each subspace, right? Or you omitted that since `m = 1` in your example (isn't that the value of `m` in your example)? Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @gsamaras I think it's `k*` for each subspace, `mk*` in total, as said at the bottom of page 3 Instead, 

> we store the m × k* centroids of all the subquantizers.

Comment: Oh missed that, yes surely that's it, I agree! I also assume that yes, `m = 1` in your example.

Comment: @gsamaras hmm I think it's `m=2` in my example (m is the number of subspaces), because I used each dimension as a subsapce. Maybe what you mean is `D*=1` (D* is the dimensions of each subspace).

Comment: Exactly! You might want to address that in your answer, thanks again!

Comment: I posted the last relevant question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388748/why-we-need-a-coarse-quantizer), if you have time, please take a look (notice this is different from the previous comment, done 2h ago).